# The repository "..." could not be reached. with Xcode 4.5.1

Tags: git, xcode4.5

I think most of you upgrade Xcode.
After upgrade Xcode to 4.5.1, I encountered the error when I committed my project,

Error dialog said,
The operation could not be performed because no repositories could be reached.
Please verify that one or more repositories are online and reachable and try again.

But the repository is on local disk, so it is online and reachable.

I can manage this git repository by other git client (GITX http://gitx.laullon.com), so the git repository should not be broken.
Newly created project also has same problem.

More over, at repositories organizer window, all titles of git projects turned red. What's happened!

I threw Xcode.app to trash, and re-install it. But no effect.

git is updated.

```
$ which git
/usr/bin/git
$ ls -l /usr/bin/git
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  2707120 10  7 20:07 /usr/bin/git
$ ls -l /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git 
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  2707120 10  9 09:38  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git
```

Please let me know if you have same problem or any solution.

Comment: Just had this problem on Xcode 4.5.2. Git repository looked (and operated) fine from command line and SourceTree. Restarting Xcode had no effect. Reboot of machine fixed.

Answer (score -3):

I re-install OSX (Mountain Lion), then Xcode works fine.

Comment: I wouldn't consider reinstalling the entire operating system a solution for any problem.

Comment: This question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351163/xcode-5-the-repository-could-not-be-reached