# Xcode 5: The repository could not be reached

Tags: xcode, git, bitbucket

I have this issue with Xcode 5 where I'm trying to commit a file to a remote git repository (BitBucket) and getting a pop up window with the following error: "The repository "project_name" could not be reached. Please verify that the repository is online and reachable and try again."

I've been working with this setup for awhile now (since Xcode 4) and didn't have any problems with it. Under Xcode->Preferences->Accounts->Repositories I saw the correct repository, but duplicated. I deleted and added it again, but it didn't help. I tried closing the project and rebooting the computer and it didn't help either. I can see the project's history under Source Control->History. I can access the repository on BitBucket.

Any idea where this is coming from and how to solve this issue?

Comment: The only idea that comes to mind is maybe that your link has changed? Have you changed your username on Bitbucket?

Comment: Nope. Same username, same password, same repository name. I have other projects and repositories on that same BitBucket account and I was able to commit and push to one of them today (using a different IDE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it seems this had nothing to do with Bitbucket.

The problem was a messed up .git folder on my machine.
My project resides in a Dropbox folder. Somehow, perhaps because of accessing it from different machines, it created copy/duplicate files in the .git folder and it messed up Git. After fixing all the conflicts Git returned to working as usual and I was able to commit from Xcode to the remote repository.

Now, if you encounter this issue, you might not have the same setup as mine or work on Dropbox or any similar service, but I strongly recommend checking your Git folder thoroughly. Good chance something is messed up there.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this helps in the tracking down of this problem, but here goes anyway:

I have been connecting to a local network git repository perfectly well for a number of months, but I encountered this problem later yesterday and nothing I did seemed to improve the situation. That included:

- Rebooting both the development machine and the server;
- Reinstalling Xcode from the App Store;
- Re-cloning the project from the git command line (which could see the repository perfectly well);
- Checking out the repository from Xcode (I was able to check out but every other operation, such as , Commit, Refresh Status etc. seemed to cause the problem...)
- Manipulation the repository with SourceTree (which could also see it fine).

Eventually I stumbled across a solution to my local issue. If I launch Xcode with a wired and wireless network enabled then I can't see the repository. If I close it, disable wifi and relaunch it then I can.

I've not had much opportunity to work out what the difference is (especially as the wifi connects to the same network and is the secondary choice for networking) but it does seem to fix it.

Hope that might help others and hopefully I can find a real explanation soon!

Dave,

Answer (score 2):

Check internet connection of system.also quit xcode and reopen it.

Answer (score 0):

Disconnecting the wired connection (physically removing the cable) fixed or maybe better stated allowed me to workaround the problem. Xcode immediately prompted me to authenticate the SSH certificate with the passphrase (without rebooting or restarting Xcode) and after entering the passphrase, Xcode successfully pushed the project.